# Android text scrolling not working with Scrollview and Textview

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollview

I was following the Android CodeLab tutorials and working on the AboutMe project. But when I went to the part of making a scrollable  textview, it somehow isn't working. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" android:layout_margin="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/avra_neel"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp" android:id="@+id/name_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"      
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        style="@style/NameStyle"/>
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp" 
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:id="@+id/star_image" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="552dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star" 
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_text" 
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="473dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/star_image" 
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.666"   
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/bio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bio_text"
                style="@style/NameStyle"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I try to run the app, the textview sticks to the bottom or the top, and when I try to scroll it down it jumps to the top. I guess I have done something wrong somewhere.
What do I do to make it work ? Please help.

Comment: share the complete xml

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`.
The `ScrollView` should only contain a `TextView`